# Does having a Lower Column break normal Form?

Tags: sql, database

,i'm working with a third party database that holds a contact table

i.e.

```
ID int,
Name varchar(50)
Name_Lower varchar(50)
```

as you may imagine the Name and Name lower column contain data such as

```
Name - "John"
Name_Lower - "john"
```

seeing as the data contained should be exactly the same, save for the lower function, I believe this breaks normal form. Probably worth mentioning this is not a computed column. There have been instances in the past where the two do not sync up.

Comment: Why do you need such a column at all? String comparisons are affected by the column's collation. Case-insensitive collation are the default for most languates

Comment: @DrCopyPaste no need for that, you can specify a different collation on the query itself. A computed column would only be needed if you wanted to put an index on the new column - but why do that?

Comment: Simple: if it violates the rule *All data should rely on the key, the whole key and nothing but the key (so help me Codd)* - then yes, it violates one of the three basic normal forms. If you have a column `lower` that depends **only** on the `Name` column, and `Name` isn't the key for that table --> it violates the NF

Comment: What does "the two do not sync up" mean? That a given Name value might appear with different Name_Lower values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it breaks NF, as one column is a direct derivative of another.

You don't need to do this, BTW. You can just have your table as-is without the Lower column, then create a VIEW that includes a computed, to-lowercase column.

Whenever you need the lower-case form, you query the VIEW; but you only update the TABLE, and you'll never have synchronization problems.

Comment: i was near certain it did, i just wanted to confirm, for clarity this is a third party DB not my own